# Unrecognized selector sent to instance when using CNcontacts

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, contacts

I am having an issue when trying to get my locally saved names of phone numbers. The app crashes when calling this function:

```
func getContactName(phoneNumber: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void ) {
     let phoneNumber = CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: phoneNumber)
        let phoneNumberPredicate = CNContact.predicateForContacts(matching: phoneNumber)
        var contactName: String?
    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [ CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor, CNContactFamilyNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor])
        fetchRequest.predicate =  NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [    phoneNumberPredicate])
        let store = CNContactStore()
        do {
            try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) {
                (contact, stop) in
                // Array containing all unified contacts from everywhere
                contactName = contact.givenName
                if let contactName = contactName {
                    completion(contactName)
                }
            }
        } catch {
        }
    }
```

The crash log says-
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCompoundPredicate cn_triageWithLog:serialNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2834201c0' and it crashes in the line `try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { (contact, stop) in`
It does not have issues on some devices like iPhone 12 Pro, 11, 6s etc., but on some devices, it crashes with an "Unrecognized selector sent to instance". Does anyone have any idea about what exactly the issue would be?

Comment: Which line crashes? What exactly does the crash log say?

Comment: crash log says - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCompoundPredicate cn_triageWithLog:serialNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x283a31960'
*** First throw call stack
and it crashes in the line  - 
 

try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) {
                (contact, stop) in

Comment: @JoiceGeorge Don't forget to respond to the help you receive. You have never once commented on or accepted a single answer given to any of your questions. You should go back through all of your questions and upvote answers that were helpful and accept answers that solved your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[phoneNumberPredicate])
```

should be:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = phoneNumberPredicate
```

It makes no sense to create a compound predicate with a single predicate. Besides that, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactfetchrequest/1403080-predicate) for the `predicate` property of `CNContactFetchRequest` states the following:

> Set the value of this property to nil to match all contacts or use the search predicates in CNContact. Compound predicates are not supported.

Note the last sentence.